# CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT not asked for permission at runtime

Tags: java, android, audio, output, record

im trying to record sound from dictaphone but on android 6+ i get permission error. 
I add code for asking permission (have 3 permissions for ask ) 2 work but 
CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT show error. Its just not ask me to grant permission. In logs its just "not granted"
Any one know in what problem ?

```
 public static boolean PermissionCheck(Activity context, String permission, int code) {
        boolean state = false;
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                permission);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{permission}, code); // define this constant yourself
        } else {
            // you have the permission
            return true;
        }
        return state;
    }

case CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT_CONSTANT: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Logger.e("CAPTURE PERMISSION GRANTED");
                    INIT();
                } else {
                    Logger.e("CAPTURE PERMISSION NOT GRANTED");
                    finish();
                }
                return;
            }
```

error

```
W/PackageManager: Not granting permission android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT to package blabla_package (protectionLevel=18 flags=0x3848be46)
```

in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT"/>
```

**[UPD]** After a lot of tries and researches  i now can answer :
Thank to google , now we cant record calls. 
Its possible only if using C code and NDK .

Comment: @Hetfieldan24 i have line in manifest

Comment: Did you implement NDK? Is it recording both the voice?

Comment: @Heena yes implemented. Its record only microphone. Somehow should be way to avoid this..but i dont know how, no experience in NDK

Comment: @Peter It was possible using NDK up to Android 9 (excluding). That's why you can see many call recording apps fail to record on Android 9. Now it has become more and more impossible. Maybe via root it's possible, but still hard. If you know how to do it via root (and without putting the app to be a system app), please let me know.

Comment: @androiddeveloper i left this idea. Not legal

Comment: @Peter What's not legal?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Like you I'm eager to know if it's possible to record uplink and downlink just with root access and without making a system app. If you found an answer please let me know also

Comment: @FahimeGhasemi I have no idea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` is not a `dangerous` permission and so does not work with the runtime permission system. `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` has `android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged"`, so it can only be held by apps that are installed on the privileged (a.k.a., system) partition or are signed by the platform signing key.

Comment: and how  i can record sound on 6+ ? just add sign key to app ?

Comment: @Peter: `CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` is not for recording sound using the microphone. That is the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission.

Comment: Is it possible to grant CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission via adb and/or rooted device ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: Since it is `privileged`, on a rooted device you should be able to move the app to the privileged partition and get the permission that way. I don't know all the details, though, as root scenarios are not my area of expertise.

Comment: @androiddeveloper: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: Suppose you do get this permission somehow, will recording work as normal recording? Or something special is needed? Some specific audio-source needs to be selected for call-recording? System apps get this permission automatically, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: "System apps get this permission automatically, right?" -- only if they request it in their manifest. With regards to the rest of your questions, I have no idea, sorry. I approached this answer from the permission-behavior standpoint; I have not used this permission personally.

Comment: @CommonsWare Of course. Sorry, and thank you for your time, as always. You are great. Have a shower of +1 :)